# Sequelize: extra column in query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i have the following table define

product table

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
  amount: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL },
  category: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, field: 'categoryId' },
  brand: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, field: 'brandId' },
  vendor: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, field: 'vendorId' },
  status: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, field: 'statusId' },
  image: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
  stock: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
  description: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
  model: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
  code: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
});
```

status table

```
const Statuses = sequelize.define('statuses', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
});
```

associations

```
Product.belongsTo(Statuses, { foreignKey: 'statusId', as: 'productStatus'});
```

when i run thhe following:

```
product = await Product.findOne({
  where: {
    id: req.query.id
  }, 
  include: ['productStatus']
})
```

I get the following query:

```
SELECT 
"product"."id", 
"product"."name", 
"product"."amount", 
"product"."categoryId" AS "category", 
"product"."brandId" AS "brand", 
"product"."vendorId" AS "vendor", 
"product"."statusId" AS "status", 
"product"."image", 
"product"."stock", 
"product"."description", 
"product"."model", 
"product"."code",
"product"."createdAt", 
"product"."updatedAt", 
"product"."statusId", 
"product"."categoryId", 
"product"."vendorId", 
"product"."brandId", 
"productStatus"."id" AS "productStatus.id", 
"productStatus"."name" AS "productStatus.name", 
"productStatus"."createdAt" AS "productStatus.createdAt", 
"productStatus"."updatedAt" AS "productStatus.updatedAt", 
"productStatus"."status" AS "productStatus.status" 
FROM "products" AS "product" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "statuses" AS "productStatus" ON "product"."statusId" = "productStatus"."id" 
WHERE "product"."id" = '1'
```

not sure why

```
"productStatus"."status" AS "productStatus.status"
```

is there and it causes an unknown column error since i don't have that column in statuses table

Comment: Do you have reverse association `hasMany`? If so can you show it?

Comment: the correct include would be `include: { model: Statuses, as: 'productStatus' }`

Comment: @Anatoly I had this User.hasOne(Status, { foreignKey: 'status', as: 'UserStatus'}); , once i comentted that out, it worked fine, weird

Comment: hi @doublesharp thank you, i tried it but that didn't work :-)

Comment: Give a try to this also `include: [ {model: Statuses, as: 'productStatus'  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.hasOne(Status, { foreignKey: 'status', as: 'UserStatus'})` means `Status` has the `status` column which is not true. That's why Sequelize knows that `Status` model has `status` column and adds it to SQL-query as well.

I suppose `User` has `status` column instead of `Status`. If so, all you need is to change association like this:

```
User.belongsTo(Status, { foreignKey: 'status', as: 'UserStatus'})
```